# R programming: Boolean operations between a group of columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, boolean-operations

In R, if a dataframe is constructed with an unknown number of columns and rows, how would a row-wise or column-wise Boolean operation be performed.

This code constructs such a dataframe.

```
nrows <- sample(3:10, 1)
ncolumns <- sample(3:10, 1)
random.boolean.matrix <- matrix(lapply(seq(1:(nrows*ncolumns)), function(x){sample(0:1,1)}), ncol=ncolumns)
random.boolean.dataframe <- as.data.frame(random.boolean.matrix)
```

Say the random dataframe turned out to be 3x3.

```
> random.boolean.dataframe
 V1 V2 V3
1  1  1  0
2  1  0  0
3  1  1  1
```

How could an AND across every row be performed such that the output was:

```
> random.boolean.dataframe$AND.rows
[1] 0 0 1
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rowMeans`:

```
v=ifelse(rowMeans(random.boolean.dataframe)==1,1,0)
[1] 0 0 1
```

Or `apply`, for example:

```
v=apply(random.boolean.dataframe,1,min)
[1] 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rowSums`:

```
as.numeric(!rowSums(!random.boolean.dataframe))
# [1] 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `any`

```
> set.seed(1984)
> mx <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1,100, replace = T), ncol = 10))
> 
> mx
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
2   0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0   1
3   0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1   0
4   0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0   1
5   1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0   1
6   1  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0   1
7   0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0   0
8   0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   1
9   1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1   1
10  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1   0
> 
> ## for the 'AND' operator 
> 
> sapply(mx, function(x) as.numeric(any(x == 0)))
 V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 
  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 
> 
> ## for the 'OR' operator 
> 
> sapply(mx, function(x) as.numeric(any(x != 0)))
 V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 
  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 
>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those questions where the answer I was looking for was among all the responses.

```
rowAnd <- function(dataframe, columns =  1:ncol(dataframe)){
  sapply(seq(1:nrows),function(x) ifelse(all(dataframe[x,columns] == 1),1,0))
}

rowOr <- function(dataframe, columns =  1:ncol(dataframe)){
  sapply(seq(1:nrows),function(x) ifelse(any(dataframe[x,columns] == 1),1,0))
}

columnAnd <- function(dataframe, rows =  1:nrow(dataframe)){
  sapply(seq(1:nrows),function(x) ifelse(all(dataframe[rows,x] == 1),1,0))
}

columnOr <- function(dataframe, rows =  1:nrow(dataframe)){
  sapply(seq(1:nrows),function(x) ifelse(any(dataframe[rows,x] == 1),1,0))
}


rowAnd (random.boolean.dataframe)
rowOr (random.boolean.dataframe)
columnAnd (random.boolean.dataframe)
columnOr (random.boolean.dataframe)
```